# Minimum code needed to write a new dynamic class in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Im trying to create a class called myNewishButton, which controls a MDrectangleFlatButton. I can then use myNewishButton over and over without writing the same code again and again. What is the barebones minimum code needed for me to pull this off? Everything i see so far looks like pages of code and im almost sure that isn't the simplest way.

I tried to write this in my py file:

```
<myNewishButton@MDRectangleFlatButton>
      text: 'this is the button'
      color: 0, 0, 0, 1
```

However, im getting a syntax error.... i do not know why.

Besides this, im then typing into my kv file:

```
<myNewishButton>
     id: 'button 1'
     size_hint_x: None
```

which im expecting to give me a MDRectangleFlatButton styled with the definition of myNewishButton.

However, besides my syntax error in my py file, something is telling me im still missing something to pull this off successfully. What is the minimum code im missing to get it all to work as it should?

Comment: The `<myNewishButton@MDRectangleFlatButton>`.. syntax is for the `kv` file...

Comment: I did that now. Apparently, still not enough as im getting  Invalid property name as the error. What else am i missing to make this run correctly?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]..